# Can't implemented Blog list in wordpress using elementor to achieve a blog url

Tags: wordpress, slug, elementor

I'm not quite sure if this is the right place for me to ask this question but I'm really stuck with this problem.

As the title said I have a wordpress using elementor page builder but I can't achieve the right slug or url that I want. I want to achieve this:

**[Site-url].com/blog > [Site-url.com/blog/article-title**

but my current url always give me this:

**[Site-url].com/blog > [Site-url]com/article-title**

I already tried to change the static page and assign my blog page as blog list but whenever I try to assign it, the design that I make in elementor won't display instead only a normal blog list without template that show.

I read from the documentation but it give a design to achieve and I already tried that it still not solve my slug problem. in my permalink I use **[Site-url]com/%postname%** but I can't assign my blog pages. can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You can try to change your permalink post name to custom structure and add your permalink to following `[Site-url]com/blog/%postname%`

Comment: I tried this but it redirect me to a not found page

Comment: save your permalink and open your post from the admin. I think you are trying  to refresh old url thats why it is redirecting you to not found page.

Comment: @IncipientInfo thankyou I not really understand why but it seems the reason is the same as you state that the page trying to refresh, yesterday I tried it and it not works but when I try this one more it works

Answer (score 0):

It's simple go to wp-admin => Settings => Permalink and set URL structure like this

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

See the image ==>
https://nimb.ws/kX0qTe

Comment: thankyou its solve my problem, but i wonder I tried this last night but it still not solve it but now it solved ^.^, and can I ask one more thing? I use sassy share button but in facebook share it doens't give the right page it only tell my [site-url].com even though I tried to fetch it in facebook developer page

Comment: Sassy share plugin providing documentation for this, Maybe it will help you
http://support.heateor.com/how-to-share-specific-page/